# How to get latest value from three tables

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I pick some data from three tables `TEST_DATA`, `TEST_PARAM` and `TEST_TEST`. When I run the question I get more rows with the same information, (serial number and attribute), except from the date/time column.

How can I sort to get only the latest value depending on attribute based on the date column?

My query:

```
SELECT pt_test_man_order, pt_test_serial, pt_data_var, pt_param_attr, pt_data_date
FROM test_data,
     test_param,
     test_test
WHERE pt_test_id = pt_data_test_id
  AND pt_data_param_id = pt_param_id 
  AND ((pt_test_man_order='8775'))
ORDER BY pt_test_serial
```

Database answer:

[image]

Comment: Are cte's supported by sqlanywhere?

Comment: Is that image showing the current result, or the wanted result?

Comment: It is the current result

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate duplicate rows, we need to use `Group by` clause in the query (e.g. `group by pt_test_man_order`). Also, if we need to select a specific value of a field from group then, we need to use the inner query as explained in [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) documentation.